# Linux Alpine: xfce4 and unsatisfiable constraints

Tags: linux, alpine-linux

I want to install Linux Alpine with FCXE4 on my old netbook but I cannot somehow get it to work. This  what I did so far:

```
# setup-alpine
```

Here is the standard procedure, I only had to start manually the wifi connection via:

```
# /etc/init.d/wpa_supplicant restart
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
```

after that the Internet connection was online.

My /etc/apk/repositories file looked like this:

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community
```

Then I executed the command:

```
# apk update
OK: 4127 distinct packages available
```

Next step was:

```
# setup-xorg-base
```

And the result was:

```
ERROR unstatisfiable constraints:
  eudev (missing):
   required by: world[pciutils]

(...)
```

I changed the community repository to the main repository, and I got it installed:

```
OK: 626 MiB in 212 packages
```

and everything was marked with [OK].

But when the last command was ran:

```
# apk add xfce4
```

I got again the error:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
   xfce4 (missing):
    requested by: world[xfce4]
```

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wiki](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/XFCE_Setup#Install_packages) just says:

```
Ensure the "community" repository is enabled in 
apk add xfce4
```

There is the package in the community repository available, [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/community/x86_64/xfce4) for v3.9 of alpine.

The error must come because you improperly configured `apk`.

> I changed the community repository to the main repository

You should not swap the repositories, you should add the repository, so that both repositories are enabled.

> My /etc/apk/repositories file looked like this:
>   http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community

Make sure your `/etc/apk/repositories` files has *both* main and community repositories enabled.

```
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/main
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.9/community
```

Comment: Oh I didn't try to enable both repositories at once... thank you, newbie's problem.. ->  solved. Thank you.